# Crystal Reports adjusting page header column width

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2016

I have a SQL query resulting in about 20 columns. There is just the page header and the details section. Unfortunately the column descriptions (page header) are to big to be shown completely, therefore the width is smaller as it should be. Now I want the columns of the page header to be as big as necessary to show all the information.

When adjusting the column width manually and exporting the report to .xls the position of those descriptions do not match the columns of the detail section anymore.

I need the page header columns as wide as necessary and I need the detail section columns matching with the ph.

**Solution**: Adjust width of the report to the needed scale. To avoid doubled columns or rows in Excel just use "Export to Excel - data only"

Comment: It would help if you could describe the layout of your report and the order of any grouped data.  You should also be more specific about the export options you are using.  There are several different export processes for Excel with specific properties that can be set at the time of export.

Comment: Its grouped by the selected rows. About 40 Columns in a horizontal line. Export in excel 2003, no formations just grid lines. I've now enlarged the report so i can widen the description fields, nevertheless when exporting the report to excel additional empty rows and collumns are added. To solve that problem i have adjusted every field so that there is no space between them, didnt worked. I really dont know how to export a report without the issue of duplicating/adding new (empty) ones.

Comment: When you export to Excel, do you have an option that indicates it will export "data-only"?  I usually have to use this export to excel to get it to stop inserting blank cells between things.

Comment: OMG, that was too obvisious! Somehow i was able to get influence on those empty column by adjusting the reports layout therefore i didnt thought about other ways... Your solution worked perfectly fine, thanks a lot!